# how to select first row order by date from a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
City       date      Person 
A        2018/05/01   peter
A        2018/03/01   Jack
B        2018/02/16    TOM
C        2018/03/01   Mike
```

Now I want to find the earliest person for each city.
The result will be

```
A        2018/03/01   Jack
B        2018/02/16    TOM
C        2018/03/01   Mike
```

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a subquery with min date for city in join with you table

```
select m.* from my_table m
inner join (
    select city, min(date) as min_date 
    from my_table  
    group by city 
) t  on t.city = m.city and t.min_date = m.date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach, it will work faster.

```
select City,[date],Person from CTE a where [date] = (select min([date]) from CTE as b where b.City = a.City);
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it appear as code. See here for help on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @rajat, this query will return both records where city = 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TOP 1 WITH TIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select top 1 with ties
   City
  ,date
  ,Person
from MyTable
order by row_number() over (partition by City order by date asc)
```

[SQL Fidddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b1f1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Using First_Value () In Sql server

```
;WITH CTE(City,[date],Person )
AS
(
SELECT 'A','2018/05/01','peter' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2018/03/01','Jack'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2018/02/16','TOM'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','2018/03/01','Mike'
)
SELECT DISTINCT City, 
    FIRST_VALUE([date])OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY [date]) AS [date],
    FIRST_VALUE(Person)OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY [date])AS Person
FROM CTE
```

Result,Demo: http://rextester.com/DLPE49383

```
City    date        Person
--------------------------
A     2018/03/01    Jack
B     2018/02/16    TOM
C     2018/03/01    Mike
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select City, min(date) as date, Person 
from T
group by City, Person
```

Comment: grouping by City and Person will not give you the required result. given this data set you'll get the entire table using this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH A (City, [Date], Person) AS 
(
SELECT 'A' , CAST('2018-05-01' AS DATE) , 'Peter' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A' , CAST('2018-03-01' AS DATE) , 'Jack' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' , CAST('2018-02-16' AS DATE) , 'TOM' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' , CAST('2018-03-01' AS DATE) , 'Mike' 
)

SELECT City, [Date], Person
FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY [Date]) Rn , *
FROM A
) P 
 WHERE P.RN  = 1
```